# Problem with installing fedora 17 in usb

Tags: fedora, software-installation, uefi

I am trying to install Fedora 17 ( 32 bit Desktop Version ) on a usb which will be run on a Eee PC. My problem is that the usb is being made bootable by the software ( Universal USB Installer ) and when I boot from the usb, then prompt screen appears which asks me to select two options:- Fedora or troubleshooting. On selecting fedora, the screen goes completely blank and nothing happens for a long time. Nothing at all. Can you help me? I have searched on the net but couldn't to get any relevant information.

Note:- My system is a ASUS 1GB RAM, 1.60 Intel Atom, UEFI system.

Comment: Try switching to a different console by hitting Ctrl+Alt+1, Ctrl+Alt+2, ... One of them may have some message displayed.

Comment: Just a warning: Fedora has [announced the end of support](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/announce/2013-July/003177.html) for Fedora 17.

Comment: @n.m. Ctrl+Alt+1, Ctrl+Alt+2, Ctrl+Alt+3, ... are not doing anything. Although Ctrl+Shift+1 seems to reboot the OS but even after all this, there is on the screen after fedora starts

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant Ctrl+Alt+F1, Ctrl+Alt+F2, ... Sloppy editing on my part.

Comment: Please do try with Fedora 19. Not only is F17 end-of-life, but new versions add new hardware support.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to verify md5 hash of the Fedora iso file you downloaded. md5sum on Linux, FCIV [Availability and description of the File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) on Windows.The Hashes for Fedora can be found at fedoraproject.org/en/verify

If it is correct try using the [usbcreator from fedora for fedora](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/%E2%80%8E)

Comment: I have used most of the softwares that come for this task. They are creating a bootable usb. The problem is with my computer. Everytime, I boot from the usb, the start screen giving option to enter fedora or select troubleshooting are given. I select fedora and the screen goes blank. Nothing happens after that. I'll try installing the latest version of fedora or linux mint and see how the things go from there.